# I want to do MouseMove event but it's not working

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', parallax);
function parallax(e){
  this.querySelectorAll('.layer').forEach(layer =>{
    var speed = layer.getAttribute('data-speed');
    var x     = (window.innerWidth - e.pageX * speed)/100;
    var y     = (window.innerWidth - e.pageY * speed)/100;
    layer.style.transform = "translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px)"

  });
}
```

https://codepen.io/nour-aldeen/pen/rEzPWB

Comment: Define "*not working*". What do you expect to happen and what is currently happening? Are there are errors?

Comment: `this.querySelectorAll` should probably be `document.querySelectorAll`?

Comment: The `.transform` string needs backticks instead of double quotes

Comment: i tried it but still doesn't work here is the error forEach(layer =>{}) parsing error unexpected token >

Comment: You will need to transpile your code if testing or deploying while aiming at browsers not supporting ES6 features. Or just write it in plain ES5

Comment: If you don't already have a build process in place, you can quickly do it here: https://babeljs.io/en/repl

Comment: I should use (`) istead of (') in layer.style.transform and its working now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use back-ticks when using templates literals:

```
layer.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px)`
```

Otherwise the literals won't be evaluated.

Comment: can u tell me why and when i should use this ..because im new in js ...thankyou

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals